# Use null.Time values in a golang template

Tags: go, templates, go-templates

I'm using gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4 to get some data from a Postgres DB and the results are coming back fine, and I can put them into json format and the world is happy... however, I'm trying to email the results using a template and have hit a problem.

The structure is (partially)

```
type DataQuery struct {
     Date null.Time `json:"DateTime"`
....
```

The template is

```
{{define "plainBody"}}
Hi,

Here are the results for the check run for today.

The number of rows returned is {{.Rows}}

The data is
{{ range .Data}}
    {{.Date}}
{{end}}

{{end}}
```

And the results of running that template are

```
Hi,

Here are the results for the check run for today.

The number of rows returned is 57

The data is

    {{2021-09-13 00:00:00 &#43;0000 &#43;0000 true}}

    {{2021-08-16 00:00:00 &#43;0000 &#43;0000 true}}

    {{2021-09-19 00:00:00 &#43;0000 &#43;0000 true}}

    {{2021-09-18 00:00:00 &#43;0000 &#43;0000 true}}
```

I tried using {{.Date.EncodeText}} and ended up with

```
 [50 48 50 49 45 48 57 45 49 51 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 90]

    [50 48 50 49 45 48 56 45 49 54 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 90]

    [50 48 50 49 45 48 57 45 49 57 84 48 48 58 48 48 58 48 48 90]
```

For the datetime fields (which might be a []byte of the strings but I'm not sure.

If I use {{Date.Value}} I get
`2021-09-13 00:00:00 &#43;0000 &#43;0000`

The other field types (string, int, float) all work fine with

```
{{Variable.ValueOrZero}}
```

I think I'm close.. but can't quite crack it for the date time fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using [`html/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template) which provides context-sensitive escaping, that's why you're seeing those `&#43;` sequences. If you want text output, use [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) instead. For details, see [Template unnecessarily escaping `<` to `&lt;` but not `>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527115/template-unnecessarily-escaping-to-lt-but-not/48527166#48527166)

Next, [`null.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/guregu/null.v4#Time) is not just a simple [`time.Time`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time) value, it wraps other fields too (whether the time is valid). When simply outputting it, that valid field will also be rendered (the `true` texts in your output).

You may render only its `Time` field: `{{.Date.Time}}`.

With these changes output will be for example:

```
Hi,

Here are the results for the check run for today.

The number of rows returned is 2

The data is

    2021-09-20 12:10:00 +0000 UTC

    2021-10-11 13:50:00 +0000 UTC
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-oiX7GexiE-).