# Underscore.js template variable name is being escaped causing it to not get rendered

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, escaping, underscore.js

I am playing around with rendering templates using with Underscore.js (Backbone.js app). I'm running into the following issue, where a part of the variable name in the template I am trying to render gets escaped when I try and obtain the template string (using .html(), .text()):

HTML file:

```
        <script type="text/template" id="tpl-note-item">
            <h1> 
                <%= noteTitle %>
            </h1>
        </script>
```

.js:

```
        var htmlString = $("#tpl-note-item").html();


        //   <h1> 
        //        &lt;%= noteTitle %>
        //    </h1>
        //
        console.log(htmlString); 

        var template = _.template(htmlString);

        html += template({ 
            noteTitle: note.get("title")
        });
        . . .
```

As a result of `<%= noteTitle %>` being escaped to `&lt;%= noteTitle %>`, the template gets rendered as:

`<%= noteTitle %>`
instead of actually substituting in the variable value from the call to `note.get("title")`.

This seems like a fairly basic use case of templates, so I am fairly sure I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just minutes after posting this (and a day grappling with this), I found the issue:
The HTML page in context is being rendered by my Golang app using:

`template.Must(template.ParseFiles(<page.html>))`

However, I was using the package `html/template`, which auto-escapes any html file being rendered. Switching to `text/template` did the trick.
For reference, a related Golang post: [Template unnecessarily escaping `<` to `&lt;` but not `>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527115/template-unnecessarily-escaping-to-lt-but-not)